# IntelliJ: Is it possible to copy to clipboard the entire watch view including all the expressions and their values?

Tags: intellij-idea

I would like to send to someone the values of certain expressions in the watch window along with the expression definitions themselves, of course. The first thing that comes to mind is be able to copy the contents of the entire watch window. However, I seem to be unable to do that.

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all the watches, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy.